# How to solve the system of nonlinear simultaneous equations (in Matlab, in Python, or in Fortran)

Tags: math, numerical-methods, nonlinear-functions

I am looking at a system of nonlinear simultaneous equations. The two variables are u>0 and b>0. How can I solve this problem in Matlab, in Python, or in Fortran? Thanks.

[image: Nonlinear simultaneous equations]

Comment: There are many references on the internet for algorithms to solve nonlinear equations, in addition to your class's lecture notes.  Such an open-ended questions doesn't really suit this forum well.

Comment: Personally, I don't think the comment is that helpful.  It's not that open-ended a question; it's merely asking for algorithm advice.  Perhaps you don't have anything to offer here, but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: Thank you. I think I should have asked that question in math communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily eliminate one of those equations by solving #1 for b.  Then use that to solve #2 for u.

You're going to have to use an iterative method to do it: guess a solution, calculate an estimate, compare to your guess, adjust and repeat until you converge.

I'd use numerical integration (5th order Runge-Kutta or something else) to calculate the integral.

Answer (score 2):

I'm honestly not sure this question really belongs here. But the solution is simple in theory. Equation 1 is trivially solved for b as a function of u. Substitute into equation 2, where b appears only one place.

Now, you COULD use a rootfinder on the new equation 2, solving for the value of u that satisfies that relation. Given a value for u, you could use an adaptive numerical quadrature routine to do the integration. In MATLAB, that would be something like quadgk. (Don't bother with an ODE solver, as they give you more information than you need. You need ONLY the overall integral.)

In fact though, the kernel in that integration is a simple polynomial of the variable t, and u^10 factors out of the integral. As such, first semester calculus will do the integration by hand, although it will take some pencil and paper. Or, the symbolic toolbox will suffice. A one line call to solve would suffice here, though it would be a long line, and I'm feeling too lazy to write it.

Having said all of that, note that the numerical integration will all be a bit of a problem, as your numbers are nasty and huge, with rather large exponents. As such, it also means that you very much want to do the solution symbolically.

Really, the point of this answer is that throwing a numerical solver at the problem is a BAD idea, especially when tools like the symbolic toolbox (or pencil and paper!) are sufficient and available.